# MATLAB: add a new row to csv file

Tags: matlab

Pretty straightforward in theory, but ridiculously complex in practice! Or I am missing something obvious?

I import my file *file.csv*. It is simply 10 empty columns named col1 to col10 (0x10 empty table)

```
file = readtable('~/.../file.csv');
```

Here is the new row I want to add to this file

```
newline = {'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'};
```

Now I want to add this row to *file* and write it back to csv.

**Solution 1 I have tried**

Add the line with

```
file = [file; newline];
```

Then write *file* to csv, with:

```
csvwrite('~/.../out.csv',file);
```

Nope.

> Error using csvwrite (line 47) Undefined function 'real' for input
> arguments of type 'table'.

Or perhaps

```
writetable('~/Dropbox/phd/sleepAnalysis/database/out.csv',file);
```

Nope.

> Error using writetable (line 124) Input must be a row vector of
> characters or string scalar.

**Solution 2 I have tried**

Just add the new line while writing the file

```
dlmwrite('~/.../out.csv',newline,'-append','delimiter',',');
```

It does write the file, but it adds one column per character to the left. Obviously not what I am (or anyone really) after here.

How it looks: [image]

Can't possibly be this hard! Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"writetable" is the right solution.  You just need to put the table first and the file name second.

```
    file = table([],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],'VariableNames',{'col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8','col9','col10'})
    newline = {'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'};
    file = [file ; newline]
    writetable(file,'out.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you. I will add if any useful: MATLAB was adding *x___* to the name of my first column (so became *x___col1*). Here's a solution to manually remove *x___*: 
https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/486616-first-colum-of-csv-imported-table-has-x___-added-to-its-name